# AttributeError: ProjectUpdateForm object has no attribute 'completed

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to add a checkbox to a form, if true, I want it to add a row to a through model for a manytomanyfield, but I can't access the checkbox variable. Here is the form that I have added it to, and it appears as expected, so half there:

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    completed = forms.BooleanField(). # this variable here

    class Meta:
        model = Update
        fields = [
            'category',
            'update'
        ]
```

Here is my view that I was hoping to deal with it:

```
def project_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.project = obj
        if form.is_valid():
            print(f"================{form.completed}") # attempt to find variable
            form.save()
            return redirect('project-list')
    else:
        form = ProjectUpdateForm()

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, 'project_portal/project_update.html', context)
```

This gives me the error in the title. So I now don't understand what an attribute is, I thought it was an aspect of the class represented by a variable. How can I access this checkbox variable so I can work with it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the `cleaned_data` of the form:

```
def project_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.project = obj
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['completed'])
            form.save()
            return redirect('project-list')
```

Comment: Of course it is, *facepalm*. I had completely forgotten the cleaning of the data.Thank you.